# HashSet adds two objects which returns true for equals() and has same hashcode in Java

Tags: java, set, equals, hashset, hashcode

The `frequencySet()` is calculating frequency of each character of a `String` in an `Integer[]` wrapped into `Counter` class which has overriden equals and hashcode. This method is supposed to return only unique frequency in a set but adds both the `Counter` objects.

As can be seen from the print statement: `hashcode()` returns equal values and and `equals()` returns `true`.

What's wrong?

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        String[] a = new String[2];
        a[0]="tan";
        a[1]="nat";
        Set<Counter>  s = frequencySet(a);
        System.out.println(s.size()); // prints
        System.out.println(getFreq(a[0]).equals(getFreq(a[1])) + ":" + getFreq(a[0]).hashcode() + ":" + getFreq(a[1]).hashcode() );
    }
public static Set<Counter> frequencySet(String[] strs) {
        Set<Counter> set =  new HashSet<>();
        for(String s: strs){
            Counter counter = getFreq(s);
            set.add(counter);
            //System.out.println(s + " : " + counter.hashcode() + " : " + Arrays.toString(counter.arr) );
        }
        return set;
    }
    
    private static  Counter getFreq(String s){
        Integer[] frequency = new Integer[26];
        for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
            Integer  a =  frequency[c-'a'];
            if(frequency[c-'a']==null){
                frequency[c-'a']=1;
            }
            else{
                a++;
                frequency[c-'a']=a; //++frequency[c-'a'];  
            }
        }
        //System
        return new Counter(frequency);
    }
}
    class Counter{
        Integer[] arr;
        public Counter(Integer[] arr){
            this.arr=arr;
        }
        
        public int hashcode(){
            //return Arrays.deepHashCode((Integer[])arr);
            int hashcode=31;
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[i]==null)
                    hashcode+=i;
                else
                    hashcode+=31*arr[i];
            }
            return hashcode;
        }
        
        public boolean equals(Object o){
            //return Arrays.deepEquals(arr,(Integer[])o);
            Counter c = (Counter)o;
            Integer[] other = c.arr;
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
                if((arr[i]==null && other[i]!=null) || (arr[i]!=null && other[i]==null)){
                    return false;
                }
                else if(arr[i]!=null && other[i]!=null && arr[i]!=other[i]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
    2
    true:417:417
```

```html
<script src="https://ideone.com/e.js/s2LcBw" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use `@Override`. You've implemented method `public int hashcode()`. That's not what you think it is. You want `public int hashCode()`. Note the capital c. add `@Override` annotations and the compiler would have errored (try it first: `@Override public int hashcode()...`, then compile it, notice the error, fix it by making that `hashCode`.

Note that your hashCode impl is extremely inefficient and weird. You've heard something about prime numbers but haven't implemented it correctly. The right approach is to multiply *the hashcode*, as you were writing it, by a prime if you must, not the next element value.

More generally, `Arrays.deepHashCode` is just fine here. I assume this is what happened:

- You wrote your hashcode impl with deepHashCode.
- The code didn't work.
- You (mistakenly) blamed deepHashCode as the culprit and wrote your own hasher.
- It still doesn't work - logical, as that wasn't the problem (writing hashcode with lowercase c is the problem).

Revert your 'fix' - this code with deepHashCode is easier to read and more efficient.

Comment: True. That's what happened -  the scene you described. hashcode impl that I wrote is just some naive thing to check. Thanks. Typos costs lots of time :) and its a lesson to use @Override if you have to save some good time.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `hashcode()`, it should `hashCode()` instead. You could have caught this bug by adding the `Override` annotation, in which case the compiler will notify you:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
```